# Calling an activity from a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have two classes. One uses a [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), the other uses an Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public void incrementCounter(int amount) 
    {
       counter += amount;

       Log.d("WHY", "why you no print");
    }
}
```

Counter is then used in the Activity for what ever it needs it for.

The other class which implements a Thread is this:

```
public class ScoreSystem implements Runnable
{
    private int count = 0;
    private MainActivity reference;

    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();

        while(true)
        {
            if(count >= 100 && reference != null)
            {
                //gets inside the if statement just fine
                reference.incrementCounter(count);
                count = 0;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `reference.incrementCounter(count);` never actually runs. **The reference is not null and points to the right activity.** I didn't post that part of the code because it is trivial and not going to help anyone, but waste your time.

How can I make sure my Thread calls the Activity?

Comment: there are two solution for this. you need MainActivity reference in your Thread class else you need to create `incrementCounter` method as Static.

Comment: I have the reference. If I move `incrementCounter()` outside the Thread then it works, but not inside the Thread.

Comment: you are not initializing or assigning anything to `MainActivity reference;`

Comment: **I didn't post it to keep question short**. I know the reference is okay. Take my word on it, the reference is not null and points to the right activity.

Comment: Maybe you can try: new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){reference.incrementCounter(count);});

Comment: *Read :* [Updating an Android Activity from a Background Thread](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=793)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `incrementCounter()` *static* as SilentKiller said and call it through some Handler or in UIThread by runOnUIThread, because MainActivity is from UIThread which may cause problem in background thread.

somethinglike:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
 {     
      public void run() 
      {
         reference.incrementCounter(count);
      }
 }
```

AND

```
 public static void incrementCounter(int amount) 
 {
    // do your code
 }
```

And check once again your counting logic.

Comment: Please explain what `runOnUiThread` does, will it run parallel like my other thread or will it attach itself to the Main UI thread? Also will this create a new Thread every time? I would rather reuse the thread. Please don't just dumb code on me. Also don't worry so much about `static` I am aware of it and don't need it.

Comment: @klaux runOnUiThread will run your program inside mainThread ..no it will not create new thread everytime..it just run the program written in it on main thread..same work like handler ..

Comment: @SilentKiller I think the reference of MainActivity may cause problem in background thread.not sure.

Comment: Then why bother making a Thread for it? For that I just remove my Thread and run my code normally and it does the same thing as your code right? My goal is to have this run in parallel.

Comment: @klaux As you wish :)

Comment: This is not our task to use which and when it depends on Requirements and we are unaware of your requirements so we just suggested you to use what in your code.

Comment: @RanjitPati  `"As you wish :)"` How is that even helpful? Why troll me like that? Let me try again to explain to you, the idea of a thread is so that the code runs parallel to other code/threads. If you remove the thread then you don't answer my question.

Comment: @SilentKiller  `we just suggested you to use what in your code` not really, my code has a Thread and should keep a thread separate from the UI thread. Or at least create a new UI Thread if that is even possible. The moment you remove the thread then you don't answer my question.

Comment: @klaux if you have seen my first comment. that comment it self is an answer. have you tried that one? `there are two solution for this. you need MainActivity reference in your Thread class else you need to create incrementCounter method as Static.`

Comment: @klaux No need to confuse. You do whatever you want. I just tried to run the ui thread method in its original thread.

Comment: @SilentKiller If you read my question or my comments, you would know that I have the reference to the object. This is the last time I will say this.

Comment: @klaux if you had passed the reference then whats the output? have you started that thread? what error occurs ?

Comment: @SilentKiller Seriously? output? It has the reference to the object. Of course I start the thread. Of course it runs... Again it won't make the call because Activity is on the Main Thread. There is no error... It just doesn't make the call to the other class.

Comment: so now you need to show full code. so we can check whether is there anything wrong in your rest of the code. current visible code is fine.

Answer (score -1):

The Activity referance obj is always null.

```
public class ScoreSystem implements Runnable
{
    private int count = 0;
    private MainActivity reference;

    public ScoreSystem(MainActivity reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

public void run()
{
    Looper.prepare();

    while(true)
    {
        if(count >= 100 && reference != null)
        {
            //gets inside the if statement just fine
            reference.incrementCounter(count);
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
    }
   }
}
```